Warning flags for accumulation of floating-point as integers?
What warning on GCC and/or clang do I need to activate for this to give a warning?
#include<numeric>
...
std::vector<double> vec = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

auto const sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);  // should be 0.0 or double{0.0}

(mistakenly accumulating floating-point as integers, deduced by 0 as int)
So far, the only warning I could generate was not from a compiler but from clang-tidy's bugprone-fold-init-type.

fyi detected by MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/19reEYe7W

I guess GCC / clang is doing an explicit cast in the implementation of std::accumulate to the deduced type of the 0 parameter (int) which MSVC does not.  This will then cause the expected -Wconversion warning to be suppressed.
